# Multiprocessing in SAP GUI using Python

Tags: python, pywin32, sap-gui

My SAP is very old and I can't make API calls with it. So, I have to manipulate the GUI of SAP to do my stuff.

I'm trying to access two SAP transactions at the same time in two different windows using Python.

To do this I'm using the libraries: pywin32, subprocess and multiprocessing.

But I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: cannot pickle 'PyIDispatch' object

and

> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acess denied

What I got until now is to open two windows (create two SAP GUI sessions) and access the transaction in different windows but one after the other, in other words, not at the same time.

This test program constitutes in 3 separated scripts:

- One have the class to create a connection, create the first session and login into the account.
- The second class is to "manipulate" the SAP GUI
- The last one is the main script.

**The Scripts:**

1. `createconnection.py`

   ```
   from subprocess import Popen
   import time
   from win32com.client import GetObject


   class Sap:
       def __init__(self, sap_env, user_id, user_password, language="EN",
           newSession=False, connectBy=2):
           self.sap_file = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SAP\\FrontEnd\\SapGui" +\
                           "\\saplogon.exe"
           self.sap_env = sap_env
           self.user_id = user_id
           self.user_password = user_password
           self.language = language
           self.connectBy = connectBy
           self.newSession = newSession

       def __get_sap_gui__(self):
           try:
               return GetObject('SAPGUI').GetScriptingEngine
           except:
               time.sleep(0.5)
               return self.__get_sap_gui__()

       def get_sap_connection(self):
           if self.connectBy == 3:
               Popen(self.sap_file + ' ' + self.sap_env)
               sapGui = self.__get_sap_gui__()
               conn = sapGui.Connections(0)
               timeout = 10
               while conn.Sessions.Count == 0 and timeout:
                   time.sleep(1)
                   timeout -= 1
               if timeout == 0: raise Exception("Fail to connect")
           else:
               Popen(self.sap_file)
               sapGui = self.__get_sap_gui__()
               conn = None
               if self.connectBy == 1:
                   if sapGui.Connections.Count > 0: # it's not good, I'll fix this later
                       for conn in sapGui.Connections:
                           if conn.Description == self.sap_env:
                               break
                   if not conn:
                       conn = sapGui.OpenConnection(self.sap_env)
               else:
                   if sapGui.Connections.Count > 0:
                       for conn in sapGui.Connections:
                           if self.sap_env in conn.ConnectionString:
                               break
                   if not conn:
                       conn = sapGui.OpenConnectionByConnectionString(self.sap_env)
           return conn

       def get_sap_session(self, conn):
           if self.newSession:
               numSessions = conn.Sessions.Count + 1
               conn.Sessions(0).createsession()
               while conn.Sessions.Count < numSessions: pass
               session = conn.Sessions(numSessions-1)
           else:
               session = conn.Sessions(0)

           if session.findById('wnd[0]/sbar').text.startswith('SNC logon'):
               session.findById('wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU').text = self.language
               session.findById('wnd[0]').sendVKey(0)
               session.findById('wnd[0]').sendVKey(0)
           elif session.Info.User == '':
               session.findById('wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME').text = self.user_id
               session.findById('wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE').text =\
                   self.user_password
               session.findById('wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU').text = self.language
               session.findById('wnd[0]').sendVKey(0)
           session.findById('wnd[0]').maximize()
           return session
   ```
2. `manipulatesap.py`

   ```
   from createconnection import Sap


   class QuerySap(Sap):
       def __init__(self, sap_env, user_id, user_password, language):
           super().__init__(sap_env, user_id, user_password, language=language)
           self.connection = self.get_sap_connection()
           self.session = self.get_sap_session(self.connection)
           self.new_session = None

       def open_new_windows(self):
           self.connection.Sessions(0).createsession()
           self.connection.Sessions(0).createsession()
           self.new_session = self.connection.Sessions(1)

       @property
       def sess1(self):
           return self.session

       @property
       def sess2(self):
           return self.new_session
   ```
3. `main.py`

   ```
   from manipulatesap import QuerySap
   from multiprocessing import Pool, Process
   from time import sleep

   def goto_trasaction(session, transacion):
       session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = transacion
       session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)
       sleep(5)


   def sap_interface_multi_process(usr, pw, env):
       sap_nav = QuerySap(sap_env=env, user_id=usr,user_password=pw,
                          language="PT")
       sap_nav.open_new_windows()
       session1 = sap_nav.sess1
       session2 = sap_nav.sess2
       p1 = Process(target=goto_trasaction, args=(session1, "TRANSACION A"))
       p2 = Process(target=goto_trasaction, args=(session2, "TRANSACTION B"))
       p1.start()
       p2.start()
       p1.join()
       p1.join()

   def main():
       print(">>> Start")
       sap_env = "string_for_connection"
       sap_interface_multi_process("usr_id", "usr_pw", sap_env)
       print(">>> Finish")

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       main()
   ```

Could you guys help me to find what I missing and what I should do?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `My SAP is very old` how old? doesn't it really have the RFC inbound connections or Gateway?

Comment: `I'm trying to access two SAP transactions at the same time in two different windows` are they different transactions or the same? They may lock the same data that can cause this error.

Comment: Where this parallelization requirement comes from? Why do you need at the same time?

Comment: 1. I think the release version is 740. Something like that.
2. In this test, two different transactions, but actually what I really need to do uses one transaction.
3. I need this parallelization cause I need to cancel some information. The problem is that SAP take a long time to cancel it so I trying parallelization in a attempt to speed up the process.

Comment: `I think the release version is 740` it's reasonably recent. I have 702 on one of my clients and they have plenty integration pipelines, both inbound and outbound, no problem at all. If you don't know the connection settings you need to consider contacting basis/admin, Python has plenty of modules for external connectivity to SAP like [PyRFC](https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC), [PyODBC](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/), etc. You pywin32 approach is not very robust and non-maintainable

Comment: `I need this parallelization cause I need to cancel some information` could you elaborate your scenario in more detail? I guess it is non-valid from the very beginning

Comment: Unfortunately, by complience resons of where I work, cannot use PyRFC and PyODBC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution after sometime of vaction.

But I had to refactory a lot of my code.

What I did was to instantiate the sap class to an object and pass this object to a function that will be executed in parallel. Inside of this function I use the sap class method to create a connection and create a session.

Here is my solution. Not pretty but worked:

```
from Modules.Sap.sapinit import Sap

def create_sap_session(sap_obj,  extra_num_sessions):
    sap_conn = sap_obj.get_sap_connection()
    sap_obj.get_sap_session(sap_conn)
    if extra_num_sessions < 1:
        return
    for _ in range(extra_num_sessions):
        sap_conn.Sessions(0).createsession()
    return

def parallel_sap_query(sap_obj, sessions_num, transaction):
    sap_conn = sap_obj.get_sap_connection()
    sap_session = sap_conn.Sessions(sessions_num)
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = transaction
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)

def execute_cancellations(sap_obj):
    create_sap_session(sap_obj, 2)
    sleep(3)
    p1 = Process(target=parallel_sap_query, args=(sap_obj, 0, "A", ))
    p2 = Process(target=parallel_sap_query, args=(sap_obj, 1, "B", ))
    p3 = Process(target=parallel_sap_query, args=(sap_obj, 2, "C", ))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    close_sap_sessions(sap_obj, 2, 1, 0)

def close_sap_sessions(sap_obj, *sessions):
    sap_conn = sap_obj.get_sap_connection()
    for session in sessions:
        sap_session = sap_conn.Sessions(session)
        sap_session.findById("wnd[0]").close()
    sap_session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnSPOP-OPTION1").press()


def main():
    sap_obj = Sap(sap_env, sap_id, sap_pw, "PT")
    execute_cancellations(sap_obj)
```