# Not pickable object using multiprocessing in SAP GUI with Python

Tags: python, pickle, pywin32, sap-gui, dill

there.

I have two daily extractions using Python in SAP GUI that consume a lot of time, and this must be done faster. So, i am trying to run in parallel two transactions for solve this issue.

I am stuck in the same problem occurred here [Multiprocessing in SAP GUI using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533754/multiprocessing-in-sap-gui-using-python) , but i cannot find the way this it was solve. Basically, it is a problem when i am trying to acess SAP GUI using multiprocessing library for Python and one of internal modules try pickle the SAP GUI session object.

This is the error: **TypeError: cannot pickle 'PyIDispatch' object**

I am trying to acess SAP GUI version 740 for extract two transactions report at the same time, and like my friend

above i cannot use RFC tools. I kwnow that is non-maintainable solution, but it will be a temporary solution for this problem.

I have two files in my code - sap_novo:

```
import time, win32com.client
from subprocess import Popen
class SAP:
def __init__(self, site): # Função que inicia a classe SAP
     self.path = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SAP\\FrontEnd\\SAPgui\\saplgpad.exe'
     self.site = site
     self.SSO = SSO
     self.con = None
     self.appl = None
     self.sap_gui = None
     self.session = None

    @property
    def session(self):
        return self._session
    
    @session.setter
    def session(self, value):
        self._session = value
    
    def connectToSAP(self): 
        Popen(self.path)
        time.sleep(15)
        SapGui = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI")
        Appl = SapGui.GetScriptingEngine
        con = Appl.OpenConnection(self.site, True)
        self.session = con.Children(0)
        self.con = Appl.Connections(0)
```

main

```
from multiprocess import Process
import sap_novo
import dill

def CX34(con_base, id_session):

    sap_session = con_base.Sessions(id_session)
    
    sap_session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize()
    sap_session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "cx34"
    sap_session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)

def FS10N(con_base, id_session):

    sap_session = con_base.Sessions(id_session)
    
    sap_session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize()
    sap_session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "FS10N"
    sap_session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)

def run_parallel(connection):
    p1 = Process(target=CX34, args=(connection, 0))
    p2 = Process(target=FS10N, args=(connection, 1))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

def main():

    sap_obj = sap_novo.SAP('Environment')
    sap_obj.connectToSAP()
    sap_obj.checkLogin(sap_obj.session,"wnd[1]")
    run_parallel(sap_obj.con)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I use dill package for understand what is happening using this

```
dill.detect.trace(True)
dill.pickles(sap_obj.session)
print(dill.dumps(sap_obj.session))
```

, and i got:

```
T4: \<class 'win32com.client.CDispatch'\>
 # T4 \[32 B\]
┬ D2: \<dict object at 0x20ba608a500\>
┬ T4: \<class 'win32com.client.CDispatch'\>
└ # T4 \[32 B\]
┬ D2: \<dict object at 0x20ba608a500\>
```

Then, it looks like a problem with serialization/pickle in win32com.client.CDispatch objects.

Anyone could help me this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guys.

I achieved my goal using python threading package. I could not make it work using multiprocess.

Basicaly, i am making two threads, one of each transaction code, and passing a session id for each function.

However, it is necessary a intermediary step for make this work. I had to use pythoncom library for pass a session object between the threads, because there is some limitation in working with COM objects and threads together in python. This topic help me to do that [Using win32com with multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764978/using-win32com-with-multithreading).

In this sense, i had to create two functions to serialize and deserialize sessions objects.

```
    def serializeSessions(sap_sessions):
    sessions = []
    for session in sap_sessions:
        sessions.append(pythoncom.CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(pythoncom.IID_IDispatch,
                                                                        session))
    return sessions

def deserializeSession(session_id):
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    #
    # Get instance from the id
    session = win32com.client.Dispatch(
        pythoncom.CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(session_id, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
    )

    return session
```

With this, i am doing a serialize before instantiate a thread, then i pass the serialized session object and run a deserialization inside the transaction function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for sharing, I did a test exactly as you said and it worked the first time, now with this concept I will be able to speed up my RPAs.

```
from sap import SAPConnector
import threading
import pythoncom
import win32com.client

SAP = SAPConnector()
sap_sessions = SAP.session(total_sessions=6)

def serializeSessions(sap_sessions):
    serial_sessions = []
    for session in sap_sessions:
        serial_sessions.append(
            pythoncom.CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(pythoncom.IID_IDispatch,session)
            )
    return serial_sessions

def deserializeSession(serial_session):
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    session = win32com.client.Dispatch(
        pythoncom.CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(serial_session, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
    )
    return session

def xk03(serial_session):
    session = deserializeSession(serial_session)
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/nxk03"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)

def me21n(serial_session):
    session = deserializeSession(serial_session)
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/nme21n"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)

def me33k(serial_session):
    session = deserializeSession(serial_session)
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/nme33k"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)

def xk03(serial_session):
    session = deserializeSession(serial_session)
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/nxk03"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)

def ie03(serial_session):
    session = deserializeSession(serial_session)
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/nie03"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)

def ml81n(serial_session):
    session = deserializeSession(serial_session)
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/nml81n"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)

def run_parallel(list_sessions):
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=xk03, args=(list_sessions[0], ))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=me21n, args=(list_sessions[1], ))
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=me33k, args=(list_sessions[2], ))
    t4 = threading.Thread(target=xk03, args=(list_sessions[3], ))
    t5 = threading.Thread(target=ie03, args=(list_sessions[4], ))
    t6 = threading.Thread(target=ml81n, args=(list_sessions[5], ))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t4.start()
    t5.start()
    t6.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
    t4.join()
    t5.join()
    t6.join()

list_serial_sessions = serializeSessions(sap_sessions)
run_parallel(list_serial_sessions)
```